# Assumptions of correlation coefficient

Tags: correlation, assumptions, pearson-r

What are the assumptions for the proper use and interpretation of the Pearson's correlation coefficient?

How is $\DeclareMathOperator{\cov}{cov}\cov(X,Y)$ affected by (mild) deviations of linearity?

How is $\cov(X,Y)$ influenced by the presence of heteroscedasticity?

Answer (score 9):

The only real *assumption* of Pearson's correlation is that the variables are interval level. There are additional assumptions for *tests* of whether the correlation is 0, but the correlation is the correlation.

However, the correlation only examines the linear relationship between X and Y. So, while the correlation doesn't assume anything about the variables, it can be misleading in some cases and for some purposes. See the [Anscombe Quartet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anscombe%27s_quartet) for some extreme examples.

It is similar to the case with the mean: The arithmetic mean doesn't assume anything about the variables except, again, that they are interval. But the mean can be a misleading choice of measure for central location in some cases.

However, it is *not* necessarily the case that the mean or correlation are poor choices even with oddly distributed data: It depends on what you are trying to measure.

The central lesson is that it is always good to graph your data first. As Yogi Berra said "You can see a lot by looking"

Comment: Could you please explain (or give a reference) why the variables need to be continuous in order for Pearson's correlation to make sense? Ditto for why the arithmetic mean makes sense only for continuous random variables?

Comment: Hmmm. Thinking about it some more, they could be count variables as well; I edited my post

Comment: I've seen Pearson's correlation assumptions discussed and documented in many places.  Many of those places say normal distributions of the variables is an assumption, but nowhere have I seen a reference.  Here's one example of a paper with the normality assumption, but no reference: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3576830/

So, do you have any references to back up your claims?