# Normality of multi-variables

Tags: normality-assumption, multivariate-normal-distribution, bivariate

What i observe from the picture below that the data is bivariate normal distributed not exact and it has a negative association but i notice that there is a outlier which i marked with black circle. if i remove this i can get a better ellipse but on the other hand i don't want to remove it only for normality and i want to execute the correlation test with data. Any suggestion that this data is normal enough to execute correlation test?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

1. Correlation [does not assume normality](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48450/assumptions-of-correlation-coefficient).
2. Even if it did, we rarely assume *exact* normality; such assumptions usually are concerned with *approximate* normality.
3. Nevertheless, the primary concern is that your data is small. From your plots it does not follow that it is either normal, or nor normal.
4. I cannot see why would you assume the marked point as an outlier. It is not more outlying then at least few other points. How do you [define outlier](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7155/rigorous-definition-of-an-outlier)? In most cases [you *should not* remove outliers](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/200534/is-it-ok-to-remove-outliers-from-data).
5. Finally, does it really matter? Your data is small, removing the point or nor, in either of the cases your correlation coefficient would be small and insignificant. With such a small data it is hard to tell if there is any correlation at all.

Comment: thanks for explaination :-) , i checked again my book and it says if we want to run a hypothese test for correlation , our data should be normal(bivariate). second, it says if i can sketch an ellipse it means my data is  bivariate normal , so if i want to sketch an ellipse i see that point which is marked as black , creates problem. and yes i got co-efficient = -0.07.(Pearson)